# OLEObjects in Visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

My code below works in Excel VBA however i am changing to VB userform. The problem is i cant use OLEObjects anymore so is there a workaround in VB to have this work for me in a userform? or do i need to put this in a long if statement. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim Fun As Variant
Dim Tmp As Variant
Dim Inv() As String
Dim i As Integer

Inv = Split("NBInv NEBInv EBInv SEBInv SBInv SWBInv WBInv NWBInv")
Fun = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(Inv)
    Tmp = Val(MainForm.OLEObjects(Inv(i)).Object.Value)
    If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp > Fun Then Fun = Tmp
Next i

Smallest = Fun
MsgBox Smallest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that these are control names on your userform:

```
Dim Fun As Variant
Dim Tmp As Variant
Dim Inv() As String
Dim i As Integer

Inv = Split("NBInv NEBInv EBInv SEBInv SBInv SWBInv WBInv NWBInv")
Fun = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(Inv)
    Tmp = Val(Me.Controls(Inv(i)).Value)
    If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp > Fun Then Fun = Tmp
Next i

Smallest = Fun
MsgBox Smallest
```